# SQL-check my database,and how to make quest for all 3 tables with 2 inner joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I created a database in mysql

[image: database]

I have 3 tables and the third table has many-to-many relationship. I need to select data from all 3 tables together (with 2 joins) and when I did that I get empty result. No error but no result...
this is query:
MYSQL

```
SELECT osoba.ime,osoba.prezime,stan.lokacija,vlasnik.pol
FROM vlasnik
INNER JOIN osoba ON vlasnik.idOsoba=osoba.idOsoba
INNER JOIN stan ON vlasnik.idStan=stan.idStan
```

`vlasnik` table is relationship table.
How to adjust the above query to get results?

Comment: Your query looks correct.  Have you confirmed the data matches up?

Comment: yes,but still no results...i don't know what to do.

Answer (score -1):

Try it the other way around, first select osoba and join it with vlasnik

```
SELECT osoba.ime,osoba.prezime,stan.lokacija,vlasnik.pol FROM osoba JOIN vlasnik ON vlasnik.idOsoba=osoba.idOsoba JOIN stan ON vlasnik.idStan=stan.idStan
```

Comment: Inner joins are commutative.